# How to manage 2 editions of a theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

At the moment our wordpress theme is only available in the '*standard*' version but in the near future we plan to offer an '*studio*' version. What do you guys think would be the best way to manage 2 versions / editions of a theme without having 2 individual reposetories?

My idea at the moment would be to have a branch called '*studio*' which gets all the features / bugfixes from the '*master*' and on top of course includes the exclusive features from the '*studio*' version.

Maybe there are some best practices iam not aware of but i had no luck searching for it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend harnessing WordPress' Child Themes functionality. So your **Studio** theme would essentially be a child of the **Standard** theme.

When creating the CSS comment/headers in your `style.css`, just be sure to reference the parent theme, like so:

```
/*
Theme Name: My Studio Theme
Theme URI: http://www.example.com/themes/mystudiotheme
Description: Managing Multiple Versions of a Theme
Author: 2190870
Author URI: http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/2190870/user2190870
Template: mystandardtheme
*/
```

**Resources:**

- [How to Create a Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)
- [Theme Stylesheet](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet)